# Class-Based View of 'User' model auto-authenticates user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication, django-4.0

I've made a class-based view (DetailView) of app user's profile and for some reason anyone who visits the view is automatically considered authenticated even without entering any credentials. This happens without adding any extra logic in neither view nor template, just basic DetailView. The code is below:

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ProfileDetail(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ProfileDetail

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', ProfileDetail.as_view())
]
```

**template (index.html)**

```
{{ user.is_authenticated }} {# returns True #}
{{ user }} {# returns the user with the corresponding id #}
```

The question is why does Django do it and is there any way to circumvent it except of using function-based view? I've looked through the docs, but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Do you want to make `ProfileDetail` only for authenticated users, mean you want make it login required?

Comment: @SunderamDubey Generally, yes. But the main question still is WHY django considers users authenticated when they visit the `ProfileDetail` and how to avoid that (if possible). That's why I included the minimum info and code to replicate such behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

To implement authentication in Django Class-Based Views, I've used LoginRequiredMixin, as it's explained here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/4.0/topics/auth/default/

Code (from Django site):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
```

Another way is to pass the view that we want to authenticate to the login_required function, in the mapping of urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
path('<int:pk>/', login_required(ProfileDetail.as_view())) #not tested
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to make any page `login_required` in class based views is to use [`method_decorator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class)<sup>django-doc</sup>

In your `ProfileDetail` you can implement in the following way:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

method_decorator(login_required(login_url="/any_login_route/"),name='dispatch')
class ProfileDetail(DetailView):
    ...
    ...
```

It will make the page login_required,and set `login_url` so that it can redirect to login page if user is not authenticated, for more information you can see docs by clicking on above method.