# Django - Redirect Unauthenticated User trying to access UpdateView to DetailView

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-generic-views

This is my last brain cell speaking.
I have a model called **Post** with title, body, author, logo and pub_date fields.
There is a page in my app that the user can **Update/Edit** the post. I want the user to be redirected to the **Post's Detail page** if they tried to access it without being logged in.
The problem is that I can't reference the **Post's pk** to redirect the user to the related page, If I want to put it simply:
the user trying to access `.../2/edit/` will be redirected to `.../2/` if they aren't logged in
I Tried using **LoginRequiredMixin** to block the user but I can't redirect the user to the relative details page.

urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='details'),
    path('new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='new_post'),
    path('<int:pk>/edit', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='update_post'),
]
```

views.py:

```py
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    login_url = reverse_lazy('details', args=[self.object.pk,]) 
    form_class = PostUpdateForm
    template_name = "posts/update_post.html"
```

I also tried:

```py
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    def get_login_url(self) -> str:
        super().get_login_url()
        UpdateView.get(self, self.request)
        self.login_url = reverse_lazy('details', args=[self.object.pk,])
    model = Post
    form_class = PostUpdateForm
    template_name = "posts/update_post.html"
```

But it returns an **empty/none** value

Is **LoginRequiredMixin** even the right way to do this?
I know this can easily be achieved without **GenericViews/UpdateView** just by getting the request and handling it ourselves, But isn't **GenericViews** supposted to get the job done easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostUpdateForm
    template_name = "posts/update_post.html"
    redirect_field_name = None
    def get_login_url(self) -> str:
         object = self.get_object()
         return reverse_lazy('details', args=[object.pk,])
```

U need **return** *URL*

Comment: This returns a 'PostUpdateView' object has no attribute 'object' error

Comment: i edit my answer, should works now

Comment: Yea but the url changes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/11/?next=/11/edit`

Comment: so this url is ok?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, you don't want the GET "next" parameter, right?
i edit my answer, should works now

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the name of user field in your Post model. I supposed it as author.

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    login_url = reverse_lazy('details', args=[self.object.pk,]) 
    form_class = PostUpdateForm
    template_name = "posts/update_post.html"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_object()
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if obj.author != self.request.user:
                return redirect(obj)
            return super(UpdateStory, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect(obj)


    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):         
        if  kwargs != None:
            return reverse_lazy('details', kwargs = {'pk': kwargs['idnumber']})
        else:
            return reverse_lazy('details', args = (self.object.id,))
```

Comment: I can't suggest an edit so: 1.LoginRequiredMixin and login_url need to be removed 2.in get_success_url the else statement's reverse_lazy is enough for this code example, 3.the second if statement in dispatch is unnecessary and instead it should be nested with the first if with the == condition 4.UpdateStory needs to be changed to PostUpdateView

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
```

and then just placing this decorator above your class:

```
@login_required
```

so its something like this

```
@login_required 
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    login_url = reverse_lazy('details', args=[self.object.pk,]) 
    form_class = PostUpdateForm
    template_name = "posts/update_post.html"
```

Comment: @login_required decorator is used in functions directly, here it makes no sense, in class the best way to make use of method_decorator so refer my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71788173/17562044) answer.